# Milkman's Push ANE not working on iOS10

Tags: ios, push-notification, air, entitlements, onesignal

I'm using the Milkman EasyPush ANE for push notification in my iOS and Android apps. Together with the OneSignal backend.

All is fine with iOS 9 and Android, but no iOS 10 devices register. 
I'm building with AnimateCC (same as Flash CC Pro) and Air SDK 23.

If I debug on a iOS 10 device and listen for the onRegFailed Event, I get:

> “no valid aps-environment entitlement found for application”

As mentioned, there is no problem on iOS 9.

When I uploaded the IPA to the App Store, I got the following message:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
>   Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
>   is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your
>   App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal.
>   Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct
>   signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and
>   Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for
>   more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
>   service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
>   submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
>   you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
>   API.

But why is it working on iOS 9 then, and not on iOS 10?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 10 you need to enable it from Capabilities, check screenshot

[image]

Comment: But this is in Xcode, right? As I compile via Animate CC and upload with Application Loader, how should I use Xcode then?

Answer (score 2):

If you use Adobe Animate CC, then check this guide [Using push notifications in AIR iOS apps](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-push-notifications.html), where they're describing how to add base entitlements for push notifications and [Troubleshooting common Adobe AIR installation errors with iOS applications](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2015/08/troubleshooting-air-installation-errors-ios-applications.html#sthash.f0mB79NJ.dpbs), section "Feature listed in application.xml file is not added in the provisioning profile:

> Example: Entitlements tag has been added in application.xml file but the push notification service is not enabled in provisioning profile.

```
... 
<Entitlements><![CDATA[
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string> 
    ]]> 
</Entitlements> 
...
```

If you have any questions about Push Notifications setup on the Apple side, then check the guide from Apple - [Adding Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html), section [Configuring Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6).

Comment: I forgot to mention "why". It's not about iOS version, it's about Xcode. Apple changed the way Xcode defines entitlements for applications in Xcode 8.

Comment: Dear Dive, thank you very much! But I do have the
 <key>application-identifier</key> 
<string>SWXA5H99MY.com.winterlife.boscogurin</string> 
<key>aps-environment</key> 
<string>production</string>
in the application.xml. That's what I do not understand...

Comment: @nbuechi, you should add by yourself. Instructions about identifiers and environments can be found in the Apple Documentation about "Configuring Push Notifications"

Comment: thanks. But I added it manually to the xml, as written. And it gives me always the same error. But only on iOS 10 devices...